# is this possible to add configurable product to cart without any option?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

is this possible to add configurable product to cart without any option ?

when i try it it is showing

```
 "Please specify product option(s)"
```

I have also try to override "**addAction**" of cart. but didn't get success.

Anyother way in magento to add configurable product to cart without any option  or not ?

Comment: The classic example of a configurable product is a T shirt. You couldn't imagine ordering just a T shirt. You'd have to specify at least the size and maybe the colour, if it comes in different colours. If you had a T shirt that was just a single size and one colour, then you'd make it just a simple product.

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid selection of option when product is configurable. Configurable products are mean to be select any option of same product type. You can use Simple product instead.